# HTML Canvas is rendering text slightly differently accross browsers

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, 2d

I'm developing a web application that heavily relies upon knowing the exact x and y location of each text character on the canvas. The problem is that different browsers aren't rendering each character to the same scale.

The font I am using is `Courier New`, I have tested in Chrome 9, FF4 beta and Chrome 9 beta.

I would like to know if there is anything that can be done. Also, is it due to how the browser itself handles text or purely the canvas API?

Comment: How are you drawing your text, which browsers are having differences, and have you verified that the font you are using is absolutely identical on each browser/platform?

Comment: If you use Flash to render your drawings instead of Canvas, it will be pixel perfect across all browsers and platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember this [article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/IE9-vs-Chrome-5-0-vs-Firefox-3-6-vs-Safari-5-0-vs-Text-Rendering-149342.shtml) about it interoperability tests between different browsers. The handling of fonts is different in each browsers. There are differences with CSS too and weight or rotation in transform. I do not think you will be able to achieve perfect rendering in each of them

Comment: That's a shame, looks like I may have to render each character with a separate `fillText()` call as long as it doesn't impact performance.